# Jython cannot find pip.ini file

Tags: python, pip, jython

Have configured proxy setting pip configuration in pip.ini file but jython not recognized that pip.ini file giving connection error.

Comment: Please give all relevant information to reproduce the problem!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.